# How to reset my profile in Windows 10 before returning PC to organization

Tags: windows-10, user-profiles, reset, wipe

I have a Windows 10 laptop with a regular domain account with no admin rights what-so-ever.  Running MS Windows 10 Pro Education Version 1709.

I'd like to wipe the profile prior to returning the laptop to ensure that there are no account credentials or caches that still remain anywhere in the profile before it goes back.

I've only done this in the past using admin accounts, but I can't seem to find any way to do this with a regular login.

Is there any technique I can use to "wipe" / "reset" my current profile back to the state when I first logged into the laptop?

Comment: Yes; What version of Windows are you using exactly?  Edit your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound Running Win 10 Pro Education v1709.

Comment: Anyways, you shouldn't need to be an Administrator, to perform a Reset.  If that option cannot be used due to the way the device is configured your System Administrator can remotely Reset the device.

Comment: I would use a liveCD and wipe the entire disk. IT would probably need to rebuild the OS anyway.

Comment: @SparedWhisle - It's trivial to prevent the use of liveCD environments as an Administrator. I don't recommend that approach for obvious security reasons.